# $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] return blank value

Tags: php

I hosted my website with 000webhost and I run the following code during upload but it returned me blank value. I suspect something must be wrong with the temp folder but I not sure how to check this.

```
<?php 
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
?>
```

Comment: Please can you post olso your upload form

Comment: `print_r ($_FILES);`

Comment: Are all the other `$_FILES` entries filled in correctly?

Comment: please share your html code also.

Comment: @Dagon this is the result from print_r ($FILES); Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => burget set.jpg [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 6 [size] => 0 ) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no value in your php.ini for "upload_tmp_dir".

The value for upload_tmp_dir needs to be set in php.ini

You cannot set this value by using ini_set().  So, you may want to run phpinfo() to check, and if you confirm it is missing (and if you are not allowed to edit your php.ini) you need to speak to the web host and ask them to set a value in your php.ini.  They may decline to do so if they wish to disallow file uploads.

Comment: I think 000webhost doesn't allow users to upload (free user btw)

Answer (score 4):

Your error is: `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR`

```
Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3.
```

Please refer this http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

to resolve this error

**To resolve this** check your php.ini file and check `upload_tmp_dir` location

```
upload_tmp_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"  // or whataver desired location you want
```

Comment: It says missing a temporary folder. But how do I know where is my temporary folder?

Comment: Check your `php.ini`. It has a directive about it called `upload_tmp_dir`.

Comment: I think 000webhost doesn't allow me to change the php.ini Any other options?

Comment: @4LeaveCover also give check for your folder exist or not if not exist then create a new and give permission to writable